# make a marker clickable only once in android google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I am displaying a set of marker in my Google Map and I want to make the makerss clickable only once. If I click on the same marker again I should get a message like `"already clicked"` or something like that. How can i do it?

```
  public void getData() {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {


    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);


            place1 = json.getString("place");


            Lat1 = json.getString("latitude");


            Long1 = json.getString("longitude");
            sensor = json.getString("sensor1");
            bin_capacity = json.getString("capacity");






            if (Integer.parseInt(sensor) >= 0 && Integer.parseInt(sensor) <= 60) {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Lat1), Double.parseDouble(Long1));
                arrayLatlong.add(latLng);


                for (int j = 0; j < arrayLatlong.size(); j++) {
                    arrayPlace.add(place1);
                    bin.add(bin_capacity);


                   myMarker= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(bin_capacity));
                    arrayMarker.add(myMarker);




                    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                     public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {


                                                         for (int k = 0; k < arrayMarker.size(); k++) {

                                                             if (marker.equals(arrayMarker.get(k))) {

                                                                     counter++;
                                                                     capacity.setText("Capacity = "+counter);



                                                                 }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean to maintain the state :

```
boolean isMarkerClicked = false;
```

And update in onclicklistener

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                     public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
          if(!isMarkerClicked){
               isMarkerClicked = true;
             //put your rest of code that will work on marker click
            }else{
             //show here toast message 
           }


 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

on marker click listener this code

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            //Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// display toast
            return false;
        }
    });
```

// marker title and messages clickable use this code

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            if (marker.getTitle().equals("Your Location")) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, map.get("" + marker_list.indexOf(marker.getTitle())).get("stylistUserId"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you can do is create a `Temporary ArrayList() or HashMap()`.

Inside your `onMarkerClick()` method check if our `temp list` contains the marker, if **yes** show the `toast` and if **not** add the marker to `temp list`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace folowing code:

```
 map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {


     for (int k = 0; k < arrayMarker.size(); k++) {

      if (marker.equals(arrayMarker.get(k))) {

       counter++;
       capacity.setText("Capacity = " + counter);



      }

     } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }


    }
}
```

with this:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if (arrayMarker.contains(marker)) {
       //show here toast message 
    } else {
        arrayMarker.add(marker);
       //put your rest of code that will work on marker click
    }
   }
  }
```